Get a group topic's messages using WTelegramClient
I'm using WTelegramClient API library, and I wanted to know how can I get full messages of a topic in a Telegram group?
I've tried finding it myself but since it's my first time using an application API, I couldn't find proper method or something like that!...

use method Messages_Search and parameter top_msg_id
